# Select a html a tag with specified display content

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and have been struggling for this problem for hours.
I need to scrape a page, with its source somehow looks like this:

```
 <tr class="odd">
          <td class="pfama_PF02816">Pfam</td>
          <td><a href="http://pfam.xfam.org/family/Alpha_kinase">Alpha_kinase</a></td>
          <td>1389</td>
          <td>1590</td>
          <td class="sh" style="display: none">21.30</td>
        </tr>
```

I need to get the information of the `tr.odd` tag, if and only if the a tag has "Alpha_kinase" value
I can get all of those content (including "Alpha_kinase", 1389, 1590 and many other values) and then process the output to get "Alpha_kinase" only, but this approach will be significantly fragile and ugly. Currently I have to do that way:
`positions = response.css('tr.odd td:not([class^="sh"]) td a::text').extract()`
then do a for-loop to check.
Is there any condition (like `td.not` above) expression to put in response.css to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance. Any advice will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any constraints? Have you tried regular expressions?

Comment: @rjustin I don't. I think there is somewhat like td:not like I specified above, but struggling finding such an expression. Do you have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another selector: `response.xpath` to select element from the html,

and filter the text with xpath `contains` function.

```
>>> response.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']/td/a[contains(text(),'Alpha_kinase')]")
[<Selector xpath="//tr[@class='odd']/td/a[contains(text(),'Alpha_kinase')]" data='<a href="http://pfam.xfam.org/family/Alp'>]
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. I'm going to try this

Answer (score 0):

I assume there are multiple such `tr` elements on the page. If so, I would probably do something like:

```
# get only rows containing 'Alpha_kinase' in link text
for row in response.xpath('//tr[@class="odd" and contains(./td/a/text(), "Alpha_kinase")]'):
    # extract all the information
    item['link'] = row.xpath('./td[2]/a/@href').extract_first()
    ...
    yield item
```